# Use output number of echo as input for seq

Tags: unix, seq

So as an input, i get `echo [number]`. For example: `echo 5`.
I need to get as output the sequence of numbers from 1 to [number].
So if I get 5 as input, I need: 1 2 3 4 5 (all on a separate line).

I know I can use `seq 5` to get 1 2 3 4 5 but the issue is that I need to use pipes.

So the final command should be like this: `echo 5 | seq [number]` which should give 1 2 3 4 5 as output. My issue is that I don't know how to get the output from `echo` as my input for `seq`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details or clarification. Do you mean that you have one program/script that sends a number to stdout and you want to pipe the output to a script that reads the value from stdin and uses it for `seq`? Is it guaranteed that the output is exactly one line with one integer number? Do you need an error handling for invalid input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `echo 5` is an example replacement of an unknown program that will write a single number to stdout and that this output should be used as an argument for `seq`, you could use a script like this:

file `seqstdin`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
read num
seq "$num"
```

You can use it like

```sh
echo 5 | ./seqstdin
```

to get the output

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

You can also write everything in a single line, e.g.

```
echo '5'| { read num; seq "$num"; }
```

**Notes:**
This code does not contain any error handling. It uses the first line of input as an argument for `seq`. If `seq` does not accept this value it will print an error message.
I did not use `read -r` or `IFS=` because I expect the input to be a number suitable for `seq`. With other input you might get unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the output of the `echo` command as follows:

```
seq $(echo 5)
```

In case you're dealing with a variable, you might do:

```
var=5
echo $var
seq $var
```

Comment: But the problem is that I don't know what the number will be, it can be any number which I don't know beforehand. The only thing I get is:  "echo [number] | ..." and I need to add the ...

Comment: Where is that value coming from? Do you have the possibility to catch the `echo` in an output file? ...